# How to avoid having Pyspark partition output result in extra empty files with name the same as partition (subfolder name)?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Here is my desire output directory

```
 parent_folder
     partition=1
         partition_inner=1
             file1.avro
             .....
     partition=2
         partition_inner=2
             file1.avro  
             .....
```

instead what i get is

```
 parent_folder
     partition=1
         partition_inner=1 (empty file)
         partition_inner=1
             file1.avro
             .....
     partition=2
         partition_inner=2 (empty file)
         partition_inner=2
             file1.avro  
             .....
     partition=1 (empty file)
     partition=2 (empty file)
```

Here is my pyspark write code

```
mydf.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
.partitionBy("partition", "partition_inner")
.mode("overwrite")
.save("wasbs://my-container@my-storage.blob.core.windows.net/myoutput")
```

what is the extra files that has the name as the subdirectory for? and how do i get rid of them?

I am using azure data factory with blob storage

Comment: Could you please confirm in which way are you using the data factory with blob storage ? using databricks or custom activity ?

Comment: I am selecting `Activities -> HDInsight -> Spark` from my pipeline